# Here flutter SDK: impossible to display a downloaded map in offline mode

Tags: here-api

After downloading the map (in online mode), deactivating the connection and selecting the same download map, we got an error and the map is impossible to display.

Is this a bug in the last version. Did someone encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example app and download Swiss. It should work: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/navigate/flutter/offline_maps_app

In case of errors check the status and eventually try to repair, as explained in this [guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/topics/offline-maps.html#repair-broken-maps).

Comment: thank you Nusatad.

It doesn't work: After launching the app without the internet we got this error

W/Configuration(21643): [WARN ] Configuration - Download metadata failed, error_code=9, http_status_code=-9, error='CacheOnly: resource not found in cache'
W/DataStoreClient(21643): [WARN ] DataStoreClient - Failed to download a valid tile, catalog_handle=0, server_catalog_handle=0, request=1@rendering, error=kNotFound
W/Configuration(21643): [WARN ] Configuration - Download metadata failed, error_code=9, http_status_code=-9, error='CacheOnly: resource not found in cache'